# where to store certifcates in windows for the software

Tags: certificate, client-certificates, x509certficiate2

I am developing windows service as part of msi. when we select msi, it will install the service and creates certficates example bootstrap cert and client cert. These certifcates are used for rest api calls(as request body these certs are send).
Can anyone help me as per security reasons where can I store client and ca certifcates in windows?
Guide me whether it should be in some folders or certifcate store.

Comment: Please edit your question and describe in detail what certificates with private key you have, who generates them and who requires access to the private key at run-time.

Comment: its a bootstrap certificate which is created by service(software) during installation. The service itself required access to private key, generates certs. This service gets connected to external cloud service based on cert validation. Can anyone help here where to store the certifcates locally in windows as security reasons.

Comment: Have you tried to use Windows certificate store? It allows to store cert + private key in a secure way (e.g. the private key as non-exportable).

Comment: Can i use windows registry to store cert+private key

Comment: certificate and private key are just data, so you can store them anywhere you want, but registry is not a common place. And registry is doesn't have special security, just regular permission like in file-system.